If calcite is used to reduce acidity in well water, will removing the calcite via a water softener make my water acidic again?
My well water is acidic. I've recently had to replace my pex plumbing with copper due to unstoppable rodent chewing. (The pex was installed ~20 years ago due to pinholes in copper from acidity and electrolysis. It was great until it wasn't.) So I now need to neutralize my water with calcite to protect the copper. I fear that the increased hardness will ruin my tankless water heater.
So, my question: will the acidity return to pre-treatment levels if the calcite is removed with a water softener? Water treatment companies recommend and would be happy to sell me a water softener. Most of the information I find on the web is from these same companies. I would appreciate an unbiased answer.
Thanks for your consideration, chemists!

There are ionex resins or zeolite formulations that both bind metal ions as well as adjust the pH to acceptable levels (see e.g.    here). Perhaps you could share an example of the water softener being recommended to you?
